# How can I catch moment when someone kill java.exe process?

Tags: java

console java application. Someone kill java.exe process by Task Manager. How can I write to logs some information at this moment before application is terminated?

```
Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) { ..... }
});
```

OR

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() { ..... }
});
```

don't execute in such situation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible. Shutdown hooks will only be executed in an [orderly shutdown](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29):

> In rare circumstances the virtual
>   machine may abort, that is, stop
>   running without shutting down cleanly.
>   This occurs when the virtual machine
>   is terminated externally, for example
>   with the SIGKILL signal on Unix or the
>   TerminateProcess call on Microsoft
>   Windows.

You can send another signal that will trigger an orderly shutdown like `SIGINT`. Killing a application should be the last resort after the application did not respond.

Answer (score 3):

some practical solutions have already been suggested, but another is to ping-pong a "last status" message between **2** applications that monitor each other. When one dies, the other one writes the last received message to a log file. Users can't kill both processes quickly enough with Task Manager.

Comment: but can kill both at almost the same time programatically. I.e., there isn't a fool proof way, but in practise, almost always works.

Answer (score 2):

Some sort of solution is to write something to a log file all the time. This way you'll see whatever was the "last breath" of the Java program.

Comment: @Dominic: depends of how you set up the log file rotation.

Comment: A bit cumbersome, but it seems like the most reliable solution among the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

you might try to start java.exe via a small naive (e.g. c++)  application  using a CreateProcess (in windows )  this application will then continue running monitoring the java process handle.  if the java process is gone it can log it.

Answer (score 1):

Give your users an orderly way to shut down the system, and tell them to stop using Task Manager to do so.